# How to fix embed not sending on kick/ban (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

*When I run my kick/ban command, I want it to send an embed to the channel the command is executed in to announce who has been banned. I have it in the code, but it doesn't post when the user is kicked. How would I fix this?*

````
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(context, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    # Conditions  
    if reason == None:
        await context.channel.send("**``Please provide a reason for why this member should be kicked!``**", delete_after=3)
    else:
        # Await Kick
        await member.kick(reason=reason)

        # Send Embed in Server
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="CRYPTIC Moderation", color=0x000000)
        myEmbed.add_field(description=f'{member.mention} has been successfully kicked for: **``{reason}``**!')
        myEmbed.set_footer(icon_url=context.author.avatar_url, text=f'Invoked by {context.message.author}')

        await context.message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed) 

        # DM Kicked User
        if member.dm_channel == None:
            await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send(
            content=f"You have been kicked from **``{context.guild}``** by {context.message.author} for **``{reason}``**!"
        ) ```


The DM part works in both commands, but the embed doesn't work in either. Thank you.
````

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: Is the member actually getting kicked and is the DM working?

Comment: @Chuaat yes everything is working besides the embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that instead of just adding a description to the embed, you add a field, but fields have `name` and `value`, and not `description`. So instead, set the description where you set the embed title:

````py
#@bot.command or something similar is missing here. Copy and paste error?
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(context, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    # Conditions  
    if reason == None:
        await context.channel.send("**``Please provide a reason for why this member should be kicked!``**", delete_after=3)
    else:
        # Await Kick
        await member.kick(reason=reason)

        # Send Embed in Server
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="CRYPTIC Moderation", color=0x000000, description=f'{member.mention} has been successfully kicked for: **``{reason}``**!') #add the description where you add the title
        myEmbed.set_footer(icon_url=context.author.avatar_url, text=f'Invoked by {context.message.author}')

        await context.message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed) 

        # DM Kicked User
        if member.dm_channel == None:
            await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send(
            content=f"You have been kicked from **``{context.guild}``** by {context.message.author} for **``{reason}``**!"
        ) ```
````